# Is there an Arch based live persistant distribution?

Tags: arch-linux, live-usb

I'm currently installing Archlinux on my new computer but Windows seems to be installed using UEFI and I'm quite in a rush right now and I don't have time to install Archlinux using EFISTUB or something like that (it seems very painfull to perform).
So here is my question : **Is there a live persistant distribution based on Archlinux (and quite easy to install) ?**
Except FaunOS because I can't find it anywhere on the internet (it seems that the project has been discontinued). In the best case I would like to have a Gnome3 desktop. Can someone help me ? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Archbang](http://archbang.org) and [Manjaro](http://manjaro.org) both are distroes based on Arch-Linux with an easy to use install script, both have ability to be used as a Live system using a CD/DVD drive or any USB drive;

In USB mode [there are some way](http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?id=1855) to install ArchBang as a persistent system.

[Here](http://rudd-o.com/en/linux-and-free-software/a-better-way-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-live-usb-drive) is a tutorial on how to make a live persistent distribution.

Take look at chakra, it has a very nice installer.

Comment: Never had the time to try this, but anyway I just figured that I didn't mark your answer as validated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running Arch on your desktop computer already, the [`archiso`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) scripts could be what you're looking for:

> Archiso is a small set of bash scripts that is capable of building fully functional Arch Linux based live CD and USB images. It is a very generic tool, so it could potentially be used to generate anything from rescue systems, install disks, to special interest live CD/DVD/USB systems, and who knows what else. Simply put, if it involves Arch on a shiny coaster, it can do it. The heart and soul of Archiso is mkarchiso.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad hassan_noori answered this question first as I didn't know yet **Arch Bang** guys have built up a script to add persistence on a live-usb install.

As for **Manjaro**, stable 0.8.11 has no possible persistence, I've been told Manjaro-dev (aka 0.9) has it though I cannot recollect my source. Might come in handy along with the distro powerful and easy to use tool to build a custom ISO called ManjaroISO. I used it last month and achieved all my goals :)

**Arch linux** can be installed on any USB2/3 device (look the wiki for "Installing Arch Linux on a USB key" with over 2GB free space in a way that *allows using your USB install on multiple machines*. This is what the distro recommends.

Be aware the rudd-o guide has great ideas indeed, but part of it is outdated especialy beware the GRUB install. I tried it and the boot failed, so continue reading for updated commands.
Using this [simple command from Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Install_to_external_USB_stick) (without the grub-mkconfig part) worked well for me to quickly install GRUB2 on external USB sticks. Or go with syslinux as nicely explained by Dirk-Jan [here](http://www.vleeuwen.net/2014/01/create-a-persistent-debian-live-usb-flash-drive) also for an external USB device (works with Syslinux 6).

Good luck and happy New Year :)

Comment: Well thanks for that detailed answer, it helps a lot. I don't feel the need for such a distribution now (mainly because I only work on my Arch laptop now) but that may come in handy at some point :)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Universal USB installer is a Live Linux USB Creator WITH PERISTENCE.

It says:

"Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.1.0.exe – September 7, 2012 – Changes

Update to support Liberte 2012.3, Knoppix 7.04, Lucid Puppy 528.005, parted magic 2012.08.09, and **Archlinux 2012.08.04.** Added WifiSlax."

It says further down the list that Archbang can be installed.

Comment: I'm running Arch on my desktop computer so the .exe isn't a solution :D